# onSaveInstanceState() in activity and fragments?

Tags: android

I have an activity which contains 2 fragments. I want to save certain state of the activity and also of the fragments, in order to restore if the activity, or the fragments, are destroyed.

So I'm using onSaveInstanceState both in the fragments and in the activity, and take the data of the bundle passed to onCreate or onCreateView.

This works well besides, when the activity is destroyed. Then in restores it's own data, but, since in onCreate() I instantiate the adapter and the fragments again, they get no state.

How do I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the cause of this, is that the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` runs before the `Activity`'s `onResume()` according to the `Fragment` lifecycle documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating

Comment: Well, yes, that's what I already noticed debugging it (and it makes sense because restoring instance state will not wait for my webservices...). But what is the strategy to solve this?

Comment: You should initialize the fragments whitout data, or fill them up with dummy data, and in your `Activity`'s `onResume()` load the data into them after your webservice calls finished. Maybe display a `ProgressDialog` while everything has been taken care of.

Comment: The question about after the user has given some input in the fragments, I want to restore that data, if the activity is destroyed

Comment: You can always initialize class level variables in your `onRestoreInstanceState()` and use that data to initialize your fragments after your webservice calls finished. I just don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Hm ok so you say when reconstructing the activity I display dummy data in the fragments + the restored user data, and when the webservice returns it will create the fragment again, with the webservice data and again the saved data

Comment: Just don't bother initializing the data fields in your fragments until the webservices finished. Leave them empty. Once done, fil out the the textfields, apply the filters whatever you have to do

Comment: Ok, the problem is as said, that when the activity is destroyed the fragments are created again (via newInstance()) and then the fragment's state I saved with onSaveInstanceState is not there anymore. The problem is not actually the webservice but the fact that when the activity is destroyed, it instantiates the fragments "normally" again, so the savedInstanceState bundle in onCreateView is null.

Comment: I reduced the problem to the minimum, and it's not related with the webservices. I did a full reedit of my post.

Comment: Don't remember how I solved this... somehow with onSaveInstanceState() in the activity, in the fragment, and using the serialized constructor parameters... accepting your answer to mark the problem as solved.